# Please add zombie features

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

For the sake of all us, who love zombie movies:

> Please add a **»28 hours later…«** feature.

Wouldn't that look much nicer, than *»1 day later«* ?

[image: Tribute to zombie land]

<sup>I even added some blood in MS Paint to illustrate this.</sup>

Comment: Wat?...........

Comment: @Rarst Zombies say _whuuuud..._

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qheHaiMZK20

Comment: It's debatable whether or not the infected humans in 28 Days Later are actually zombies...

Comment: @jmort253 Feel free to add an answer... at least your name starts with "mort"ality ;)

Comment: http://theoatmeal.com/quiz/zombie_bite

Comment: @Wyck http://theoatmeal.com/img/quizzes/generated/7_58_minutes.jpg

Comment: @kaiser but ins't the two zombie films that are based on the number 28 are weeks and days, not hours... So 28 hours later should have no reference to zombies until it gets to 28 days later?...

Comment: @Brady First: Hey! Long time not seen! :) Thought about 28 days later, but a) I'm sure the community user will delete the room before that and b) it's just a **hidden feature**, that won't be seen by too many eyes, but "28 days later" is b.1) built in (I guess) and b.2) won't be seen by everyone, as the chance that someone hits an empty/silent chat room exactly 28 days later is equal to zero.